# Como obter um valor correto usando o ponto?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
preco_casa = float (input("Qual o preço do imóvel?"))
seu_salario = input("Qual o seu salário mensal?:")
anos_a_pagar = input("Quantidade de anos a pagar pelo imóvel:")
valor_prestacao = preco_casa / (anos_a_pagar *12)
print (" O valor da prestação será de R$%.2f" % valor_prestacao)
```

[image: Erro quando digita]

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 2):

Tratar isto corretamente pode dar um pouco de trabalho, mas uma solução básica para um exemplo simples assim seria remover o ponto se existir um, algo assim:

```
preco_casa_raw = input("Qual o preço do imóvel?")
preco_casa = float(preco_casa_raw.replace('.', ''))
seu_salario = float(input("Qual o seu salário mensal?:"))
anos_a_pagar = float(input("Quantidade de anos a pagar pelo imóvel:"))
valor_prestacao = preco_casa / (anos_a_pagar * 12)
print (" O valor da prestação será de R$%.2f" % valor_prestacao)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/7AjLfu). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/uizmlrtu-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/String/StripString.py).

Terá que fazer em todos que entram valores numéricos.

Comment: Obrigado!! deu certo.